# Issues with CSS drop down menu, z-index, iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm a newbie to CSS and have tried many solutions offered on this question before, but I think my problem may be with something hiding my dropdown menus. I have also tried many of the z-index solutions to no avail. I am also using an iframe to display whatever the user clicks on in the same page. I know that part works so far but have no clue why my menus do not show. I've tried to keep it as simple as possible. I will worry about design later. Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Xu7E/1/

```
body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;   

}

a:visited {
    color:orange;

}

#wrapper {
    width:900px; margin:0px auto; background-color:#EEEEEE; 

}

#top { width:100%;  background-color:black; overflow:hidden;

}


#logo {     float:left; margin: 0 0 0 10px; 

}

#socialmedia { float:right; padding:0 10px 0 0; 

}

#socialmedia img {
            height:24px; width:24px; 
}

#socialmedia p {
     color:white;
}


#topnav {   clear:both; background-color:#444444;

            padding-top:0.001em;        
            padding-bottom:0.001em;

}

#content {

    background-color:red; width:100%; padding-top:0.001em; 
    height:700px;

}


/*menu*/

ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

ul ul {
    display:none;

}

ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;


    }

/*iframe same size as content div*/ 
iframe {


    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your inner  menus to parent "li" tag so it could look like this:

```
<ul>Main menu
<li>Dropdown menu
  <ul>
    <li>Dropdown child</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now you have this:

```
<ul>Main menu
<li>Dropdown menu</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Dropdown child</li>
  </ul> 
</ul>
```

And you can also add position: absolute to your inner ul menu, so it could draw above everything else.

```
ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute; 

    }
```

Check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8Xu7E/3/ (It is setup for first menu item only, for now)

Updated fiddle with every menu working: http://jsfiddle.net/8Xu7E/5/